# ReactNative expo) Error starting tunnel TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received null

Tags: react-native, expo

Hello i'm trying to run my react native app with expo,
but when I start with tunnel, I've got error.
I'm using m1 macbook air

And the message is
`Error starting tunnel TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received null`

and this is about message.

[image]

my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "siban",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~0.16.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

there's no solution about my problem, thankyou for reading my problem.